# Screen recorder flickering and black triangle on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, desktop-recording, obs-studio, video-recording

When I'm recording a video with "Simple Screen Recorder" or "OBS" it flickers black every few seconds. With OBS, it flashes black triangles which is really annoying and requires me to completely re-record my 1-hour video again.

This has only been going on for less than 3 weeks. The reason that I got OBS was to see if this different software worked. Turned out it did the same thing. Might this issue have something to do with drivers? I think its the software up-to-date anyway.

I messed around with almost all the settings and nothing seems to fix it. What should I do?

It was tricky to capturing the flickering, but at least you can see the black triangle in the screenshot below.
[image: Black triangle]